# Find a node which is connected to all start nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i'm trying to model a cypher query for the following scenario:

I have 3 start nodes A, B, C and i'm trying to find n nodes D which are related to all three start nodes. At the end I will reduce the `weight` property of the relationships and choose the node with the highest weight.

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
MATCH (a:Node {name: "A"})-[r1]-(d)
, (b:Node {name: "B"})-[r2]-(d)
, (c:Node {name: "C"})-[r3]-(d)
RETURN d.name
, r1.weight + r2.weight + r3.weight AS Weight
ORDER BY Weight DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Only return d's that match all of a, b, c; add up the weights of those relative relationships; sort descending by weight; and pick off the first.

Comment: Just make sure to use labels with your nodes! Otherwise finding them later will be slow. (and without indexes)